# AXIS cameras (or concretely P13XX seria) support ONVIF standard fully or partly?

Tags: camera, onvif

Have AXIS IP video camera, P1344.

Camera support ONVIF standard. Camera support video analitycs (motion detection), events (through web interface and AXIS HTTP API).

ONVIF standard discovery here:

- [Onvif core specification ver 1.01](http://synesis.ru/images/stories/Articles/onvif/onvif_core_specification_ver_1.01.pdf) (and 1.02)
- [Onvif test specification ver 1.01](http://synesis.ru/images/stories/Articles/onvif/onvif_test_specification_ver1.01.pdf)

I connect to camera through PHP SOAP and *can* access next groups of methods:

- Device discovery
- Device management
- Imaging configuration
- Real time streaming
- PTZ control

But next groups of methods *can't* access:

- Video analitycs
- Event handling *(have partly access)*

**Can anyone explain next questions:**

- AXIS cameras (or concretely P13XX seria) support ONVIF standard fully or partly?
- If camera support ONVIF standard fully - can anybody explain how to enable access to Video analitycs methods?

Thanks. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

[ONVIF video analytics](http://www.onvif.org/specs/srv/analytics/ONVIF-VideoAnalytics-Service-Spec-v210.pdf) is a relatively new addition to the standard and a fairly sophisticated feature. A quick look at Axis info for this camera model indicates that they do motion detection but not quite 'analytics.'

Let us know what you find out, please. Axis people, chime in at any time!

Answer (score 0):

You can now install a video analytic called vmd 2.1 on most axis cameras or encoders that support analytics, this analytic is free from the axis Web site.